# Is dequeueing reusable cells really necessary if those cells are unique within a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Consider a tableview which is not really used to display large amounts of data of the same kind, but more as a means of laying out the interface. In this tableview there are only three cells, each cell has it's own implementation as a subclass of UITableViewCell.
I was wondering if it would make sense to use the dequeueing practice in such a tableview, since no cells are the same.
Also: what if I had more cells, each with it's own implementation, but not displayable within one screen?
And what happens if there are, say, 8 cells of different kinds and two cells of the same kind. When can I spare dequeueing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in your example of 3 unique cells, there is no need for dequeing.  The queue is an optimization for showing many cells of the same type.

For your more cells case, each unique, still don't deque.

For 8 cells, with one or two unique, you still probably don't need to deque, since there will only be one redundant cell, and with only 8 cells, there will not be a lot of re-creation of cells.